# Using virtualenv in sublime text project that works for different users

Tags: python, virtualenv, sublimetext3

I'm editing a Python project in Sublime Text 3 that uses virtualenvs. I'd like to define a build step that runs unit tests via setup.py inside of a virtualenv.

The challenge is that I want to be able to commit the foo.sublime-project into version control and have it work for everybody without modification. Assume that we are enforcing the use of virtualenvwrapper on the project, so that the virtualenv is in a known location (`~/.virtualenvs/foo`) on each machine.

Is there any way to configure the sublime-project file without hardcoding the full path? For this to work on my machine, I do this:

```
{
    ...
    "build_systems":
    [
        {
            "name": "Unit tests",
            "cmd": ["/Users/lorin/.virtualenvs/foo/bin/python", "setup.py", "test"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Ideally, I'd do something like this instead:

```
"cmd": ["~/.virtualenvs/foo/bin/python", "setup.py", "test"]
```

But Sublime doesn't seem to be able to resolve the `~` into the user's home directory.

*Edit*: We use git for version control

Comment: Is the config file JSON or Python code?

Comment: Ah, they're JSON. If it was Python you could use the `os` module...

Comment: @alko I'm using git. I'll add that to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with Sublime, and can't suggest a direct approach to this task.

As a workaround, you can set a `post-receive` hook that configures your package. You can have a sample config file under version control, and build a real config using `pwd` in bash, or  `os.path.expanduser` in python.